# Searching an element of an array against all elements of another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, search

I have created a script that allows me to import a CSV as a multidimensional array, run a search through each row of the array, and if the search string matches any element in a row, returns the entire row to a new array, by writing:

```
require 'csv'
array = CSV.read('CSVlist.csv') #=> [["Name1", "8675309"],["Name2", "5557891"], ["Name3", "5557890"]]
shifted_array = Array.new
results_array = Array.new

while array.empty? == false
    shifted_array = array.shift 
    shifted_array.each do |f|
        if f =~ /8675309/  
           shifted_array = shifted_array.join(",") #=> ["Name1,8675309"]
           results_array.push(shifted_array)
        end
    end
end
puts results_array #=> ["Name1,8675309"]
```

The above works properly.  However, instead of searching merely for one string (`/8675309/` above), I want to search through the array and return any element from another array (which is an imported text file).  I have created the comparison array, but how do I search the primary array (`array`) against another array (`numbers_array`, below) instead of a string?

```
require 'csv'
array = CSV.read('CSVlist.csv') #=> [["Name1", "8675309"],["Name2", "5557891"], ["Name3", "5557890"]]
shifted_array = Array.new
results_array = Array.new
numbers_array = File.readlines("list1.txt").map &:split #=> ["5551234", "5557890", "8675309"]

while array.empty? == false
    shifted_array = array.shift
    shifted_array.each do |f|
        if f =~ ???? # want the search to compare f to any element in numbers_array  
            shifted_array = shifted_array.join(",")
           results_array.push(shifted_array)
        end
    end
end
puts results_array  #=> desired output is ["Name1,8675409", "Name3,5557890"]
```

Comment: Don't post the code. Write what you are trying to do (preferably example input, output).

Comment: @sawa Code is good, too!. Both are better than one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select), [`.any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), [`.include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F), and 
[`.map`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), which together would look something like:

```
results_array = array.select{ |row|
  row.any?{ |e| numbers_array.include? e }
}.map{ |row|
  row.join(',')
}
```

This code first *selects* only the rows of `array` which *include* *any* of the elements in `numbers_array`, then *maps* each one with a `join`.

With that statement, your entire code block can be shortened to:

```
require 'csv'

array = CSV.read('CSVlist.csv')
numbers_array = File.readlines('list1.txt').map(&:split)

results_array = array.select{ |row|
  row.any?{ |e| numbers_array.include? e }
}.map{ |row|
  row.join(',')
}

puts results_array
```